# C++ // G++ getline() / After compiling one of the raw doesn t get input

Tags: c++, g++, getline

**Greetings fellas;**

So after i compile the following code ,the MusicIns.shortDescription object don t want to receive any input and just switching to the next object ,what id wrong in my code ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 class Instruments{
public :
 int weight; 
 string size; 
 string name; 
 string shortDescription;
 string designation;
};


    int main(){

 Instruments MusicIns;

  cout<<"Please enter instrument name: "<<endl;
  getline(cin, MusicIns.name);
  cout<<"Please enter the size"<<endl;
  getline(cin, MusicIns.size);
  cout<<"Please enter the weight: "<<endl;
  cin>>MusicIns.weight;
  cout<<"Please enter a small description: "<<endl; 
  getline(cin, MusicIns.shortDescription);
  cout<<endl; 
  cout<<"Please describe the instrument designation: "<<endl; 
  getline(cin, MusicIns.designation); 
  cout<<endl;

   cout<<"============="<<endl; 
   cout<<MusicIns.name <<endl; 
   cout<<MusicIns.weight <<endl;
   cout<<MusicIns.designation <<endl; 
   cout<<MusicIns.shortDescription <<endl; 
   cout<<MusicIns.size <<endl; 
return 0;
};
```

*Don t blame me too much for my level or syntax i am still noob.*

P.s. Thank you in advance for any help !

Comment: it is compiling ,but when i RUN it it just showing the message ,dooesn t get input and passing for the next message that is working normaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `cin>>MusicIns.weight;`, there is a newline remaining in the stream. So the new line will be assigned to the `MusicIns.shortDescription`. Add this line to ignore the newline:
`cin.ignore(100, '\n');` before `std::getline(std::cin, MusicIns.shortDescription);`

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do have "MusicIns.shortDescription" to receive an input is to do this method.

```
cin.get();
```

This method will catch any characters after you have terminated from the input.

```
  cout<<"Please enter instrument name: "<<endl;
  getline(cin, MusicIns.name);
  cout<<"Please enter the size"<<endl;
  getline(cin, MusicIns.size);
  cout<<"Please enter the weight: "<<endl;
  cin>>MusicIns.weight;
  cout<<"Please enter a small description: "<<endl; 
  std::getline(std::cin, MusicIns.shortDescription);
  cin.get();// new line
  cout<<endl; 
  cout<<"Please describe the instrument designation: "<<endl; 
  getline(cin, MusicIns.designation); 
  cin.get();// new line
  cout<<endl;
```

Comment: You misplaced the `cin.get()` call.